# Node JS class instantiation expected behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am curious to know that when you create a class as follows, does this class become a new instance for every file import.

```
class _Http {

}

let Http = new _Http();
export default Http;
```

Is this class newed up every time I require or import the file. For example:

If I import the file into view/splash.js and then into view/groups.js as follows:

import http from '../../utils/http';

Is this the same instance? I have read that this is a singleton pattern but it seem like the import would new up the instance.

Comment: No, a module is not evaluated multiple times when it is imported at multiple locations.

Comment: Yes, this is a singleton pattern and should therefore be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this class newed up every time I require or import the file.

No. What you've exported is the **variable** `Http`. Your initialization of that variable happens only once (given your code).

> If I import the file into `view/splash.js` and then into `view/groups.js` as follows:
>
> ```
> import http from '../../utils/http';
> ```
>
> Is this the same instance?

Yes. It's the same variable (technically, a *live binding* to the variable), which can only contain one thing (in this case, a reference to the instance you created).

In fact, if your code in the module defining it *changed* the value at some point, that change would be visible in all of the modules using it. You're genuinely exporting a live link to the variable, not a copy of its value. (These semantics may not be perfectly preserved by things that take ES2015 module syntax and turn it into something else, but that's how it's defined to work.)

For instance, if you had this:

```
export let a = 0;
setInterval(() => { // For demonstration purposes only
    ++a;
}, 500);
```

and then used it like this:

```
import { a as theVar } from './mod.js';
const display = document.getElementById("display");
setInterval(() => {
    display.innerHTML = String(theVar);
}, 50);
```

in this page:

```
<body>
  <p id="display"></p>
  <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

on a browser like the current Chrome which has native support for ES2015+ modules, you'd see that `script.js` sees the changes `mode.js` makes to `a` in its `theVar` binding. [Live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fa5lfv4hXd68Pa0adcW0?p=preview) *(again, requires a cutting-edge browser with modules support)*.

Comment: Thank you. This was my initial conclusion so I used this pattern everywhere. Then I started reading articles talking about issues with caching and that in some cases singletons were not really singletons. Some of the articles show crazy code using ES6 Symbols. I appreciate the response.